# Voltage drop across junctions in a bjt transistor

Tags: transistors

[image]

Above is a npn transistor with a battery connected across emitter and collector.

My textbook and all online resources seem to say this: No current flows in above circuit because the emitter-base junction is not forward biased. The current will flow when another battery is connected across emitter-base junction.

But doesn't the existing battery across emitter-collector *already* make the emitter-base diode forward biased? Where would all the voltage of that battery appear?

Observations:
If emitter-base junction is not forward biased, then both the junctions will have large but *same*  resistance.  This means half the battery voltage appears across each junction. This makes the emitter-base junction forward biased.

Where is my error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where is my error?

There will always be a leakage current from collector to base and emitter (\$I_{CEO}\$). This might be in the region of 100 nA and, at that current, the base emitter junction appears to be forward biased as if that 100 nA were flowing through a diode. There might be about 0.2 volts dropped across base emitter in this scenario.

Comment: Does that mean the base-emitter junction doesn't offer large resistance compared to the base-collector junction? If I get this correctly, almost all the voltage appears across the base-collector junction!

Comment: I get that just 0.2V appears across base-emitter because of the tiny 100nA leakage current. Still don't see why the emitter-collector battery fails to force the emitter electrons all the way into collector, thus increasing the current value...

Comment: *If I get this correctly, almost all the voltage appears across the base-collector junction!* Yes, the CB-junction is in **reverse mode** while the BE-junction is in **forward mode**. In reverse mode there can be a large voltage and little current. In forward mode there will only be a small voltage, less than 1 V, here only about 0.2 V as the current (set by the CB-junction which is in reverse and only leaking) is very small.

Comment: *don't see why the emitter-collector battery fails to force the emitter electrons all the way into collector* The battery can try but the CB junction is in reverse and only allows some electrons to "leak through". Most of the electrons cannot make it into the collector.

Comment: I couldn't have put it better myself @Bimpelrekkie

Comment: Yeah but if I add a tiny(0.7V) base-emitter battery, suddenly the emitter electrons could get into base and then into collector. Intuititively I still feel the emitter-collector battery should provide this tiny voltage... Thank you both :) Sorry if I sound naive I'm new..

Comment: @beccabecca just review how much voltage is dropped across a forward biased diode at low currents. A rule of thumb is that the BE voltage increases or decreases by 0.1 volts for every decade change in BE current. So, if we say the BE drops 0.6 volts with 1 mA, it will drop 0.5 volts at 100 uA, 0.4 volts at 10 uA, 0.3 volts at 1 uA and 0.2 volts at 100 nA. It's a rule of thumb but if you look at (say) the [1N4148 diode](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/0/2/2/c/c/51781965ce395f8350000000.png) you can see this.

Comment: @beccabecca your doubt is legitimate. Transistor action is mainly due to diffusion, not drift. The explanation you have been given is valid for two diodes back to to back. But two diodes back two back a transistor do not make :-). When in a transistor you add the B-E circuit, you are supplying charge from outside the C-E path. That tiny charge - linked to Ib - calls for compensation that can come from the emitter, but along with that tiny charge comes a lot of other charge that diffuse in base (against the field) and is collected by the collector.

Comment: *Intuititively I still feel the emitter-collector battery should provide this tiny voltage* How can it? The CB isn't cooperating. Only applying enough **forward current** to the BE-junction can make the electrons "go so fast enough" so that they can "jump over" the barrier of the CB in reverse. It takes a while to understand the BJT, we've all been there :-)

Comment: @Andyaka I see diode curve (I vs V) is flat at 0.2V and rises noticeably only after 0.7V. But aren't you assuming the junction voltage depends on the leakage current and not the other way around?

Comment: I mean if the emitter-collector battery *first* puts a 0.7V drop across base-emitter, then this forces emitter electrons into base and then into collector. We will have significant current corresponding to the 0.7V drop. Probably I should take a break and read some more haha

Comment: It's not flat at 0.2 volts - the graph is not showing below 100 uA so, project down following the general trend to ge the current at 0.2 volts @beccabecca. To get 0.7 volts dropped across BE you would need to have around 10 mA of leakage current flowing.

Comment: @SredniVashtar thank you:) with base open, the equivalent circuit is indeed two discrete back to back diodes right? Because if we connect back to back diodes to a battery, one diode will get forward biased with just *~ 0.2V* across it and rest of the voltage appears across the other diode..

Comment: @beccabecca I am not sure that is what will happen. 0.2V is way too much. Have you tried simulating it *and* breadboarding the circuit with two diodes?

Comment: @SredniVashtar do you mean that 0.2V is way too much or that 0.7V is way too much?

Comment: @beccabecca 0.2V is too much. I just simulated it, and with 1n4148 I get some 0.05V on the 'forward biased' one. The rest of the voltage drops across the reverse biased one.

Comment: @SredniVashtar how much current flowed as a matter of interest?

Comment: @Andyaka about 10 nA. I used Microcap (that's your fault! - I mean, thank you). So, qualitatively the reasoning is sound, it just needs a bit of qualitative correction. I will try to breadboard the transistor circuit with a floating base. I also remember the strange things that can happen with an open base BJT, as Bob Pease pointed out in an April's Fools day article (about the simplest oscillator ever).